# React: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I get this error while I’m trying to login, can anyone help me out please

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.signInWithEmailAndPassword is not a function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFU4t.png)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import auth  from '../node_modules/firebase';

const Login = () => {
    const [username, setUsername ] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword ] = useState('');
    
     const handleLogin = async () => {
        
          const response = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            username,
            password
          );
    
          const { user } = response;
    
        }

        const handleUsername = event => {
            setUsername(event.target.value)
        }

        const handlePassword = event => {
            setPassword(event.target.value)
        }
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="container col-md-4 col-sm-10 mt-5">
                  <div class="card shadow">
                      <form className="container mt-4" >
                         <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" 
                           placeholder="Email"  onChange={handleUsername}/>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" 
                          placeholder="password"  onChange={handlePassword}/>
                         </div>
                        <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center mb-3">
                           <a  className="btn btn-warning col-md-7 col-sm-12" 
                           type="submit" onClick={handleLogin}>Log in</a>
                        </div>   
                     </form>
                 </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work the way you expect:

```
import auth  from '../node_modules/firebase';
```

If you want to import Firebase libraries, you should follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize).  This might work better:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
const auth = firebase.auth();
```